# How to delete all bookmarks of a PDF file in Mac?

Tags: mac, pdf, bookmarks

I read PDF books and I used to make a lot of bookmarks.

After some time , I don't need the old , I need the newer.

(Not a good habit.)

[img of may case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAoYT.png)

How to delete all bookmarks of a PDF file in Mac?

One or two Command line is quite welcomed. Python is OK.

PDFtk seems not available on Mac .

Comment: Apple's PDF Kit, try it